# Memory barrier and java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition example

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a question regarding memory barriers when using a `Condition` provided by a `Lock`.

Regarding the example provided in [the javadoc for `Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), I have a question about the use of:

```
int putptr, takeptr, count;
```

Shouldn't these attributes be declared volatile? As I understand it from the example, a thread might not see the modifications of, e.g., `count`.

Or is it that, when `signal()` is called, all modifications made since the lock was acquired are visible to other threads? Much like some code in a `synchronized` block?

If yes, are the modifications visible when `signal()` is called, or when `unlock()` is called on the lock?

Thanks.

Edit: I see in the javadoc of `Lock`:

> All Lock implementations must enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock, as described in section 17.4 of The Java™ Language Specification:
>
> - A successful lock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Lock action.
> - A successful unlock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Unlock action.
>
> Unsuccessful locking and unlocking operations, and reentrant locking/unlocking operations, do not require any memory synchronization effects.

Do they mean: "A successful lock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as entering a `synchronized` block", and "A successful unlock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as exiting a `synchronized` block"?

Comment: the effect is the same as `synchronized` and `Object.wait(), Object.notify()`

Comment: `await()` does unlock upon entering, and lock upon exiting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you should read into it is, all writes that occur prior to a `lock.unlock` are visible to all subsequent `lock.lock`.  A thread that is `await`ing, when woken up, will essentially do `lock.lock`.  So all writes that occurred since the previous unlock will now be visible.

The `signal` has no memory semantics, as your latter point states `or when unlock() is called on the lock` is correct.

> Do they mean: "A successful lock operation has the same memory
>   synchronization effects as entering a synchronized block", and "A
>   successful unlock operation has the same memory synchronization
>   effects as exiting a synchronized block"?

Yes, exactly!  More specifically the compiler will issue monitorenter and monitorexit byte code instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.